# How to use reduce in this case?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Solution:
    def calculateMinimumHP(self, dlist):
```

`dlist` is a list of lists. Sometimes `dlist` values is just like:

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4]].....
```

the sub list only contains one item.I need to sum the whole list value. I can use `for` to add the value one by one

OR I could use `reduce()`...

I write as :

```
reduce(lambda x,y:x+y, [dlist[z][0] for z in dlist[z]])
```

It is not correct, it always gives me the error

```
local variable 'z' referenced before assignment
```

How could I fix the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to iterate through `dlist`, not through `dlist[z]`

```
[z[0] for z in dlist]
```

Even better, you can make it a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), like this

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, (z[0] for z in dlist), 0)
```

The last parameter to [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) is the default initializer value to use. *The advantage of using a generator expression is that, you don't have to really build the temporary list, which you prepared with the list comprehension.*

More good news, you don't have to use `reduce` at all (moreover [the BDFL doesn't encourage using it](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196)). Use [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function and the generator expression, like this

```
sum(z[0] for z in dlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also more interesting way:

```
sum(sum(dlist, []))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you think of your input as an iterable-of-iterables (as opposed to strictly a list-of-lists), you can `sum` each inner iterable, then `sum` the sums:

```
def sum_of_sums(iterables):
    return sum(sum(itr) for itr in iterables)
```

This has the advantage of working for *any* iterable of iterables, not just a list of lists.  It does not assume the lists are non-empty (`itr[0]` on an empty list would raise an `IndexError`), or even that the iterables can be subscripted at all (`itr[some_index]` on a generator is a `TypeError`).  The only requirement is that the inner iterables be valid inputs to `sum` --- meaning they contain only "number-like" objects.

The only drawback I see is that it does not assert that the inner lists are strictly *one* element each, so badly-formed input will return a plausible but probably wrong value.  That said, verifying your data and operating on it should be two distinct steps:

```
def calculateMinimumHP(self, dlist):
    # Unless your class has already verified this
    # somewhere else...
    if not self._is_valid_dlist(dlist):
        raise ValueError("Meaningful error message.")
    return sum_of_sums(dlist)
```

By the way, if your program is dealing with lots of awkward iterables like lists-of-lists, check out the [`itertools` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), especially the [recipes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) section.